# What happens when android studio syncs a project?

Tags: android-studio

When we open a project in the android studio, it automatically starts syncing. What does happen during this process?

Answer (score 0):

The `Build` window already tell you what they are doing.

[image]

First, apply `ijinit.gradle`, this seems a [Initialization Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

Then apply `settings.gradle`, it indicates [modules needs to include for building](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#settings-file).

After knowing what modules should be included, it will load and configure the whole project with [project level `build.gradle`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#top-level), which is a configuration for all the modules inside this project.

Then it will traverse all modules and apply [module level `build.gradle`](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/#module-level) for each module, and cross configure them (for module dependencies, I think.)